# Adding multiple update params sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net

This code is part of a SqlDataSource:

```
<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="surname" Type="String" />     
   </UpdateParameters>
```

How can i code this so i can add multiple parameters, since i can only seem to add one at a time. I do not wish to place these update params in my .aspx file since i wish to seperate my database related items.

```
SqlDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add(parameter);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with adding them one at a time?

Comment: Hm nothing i suppose, i just dont like to see 8 times the same line. But it seems i have little choice on this mather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your params in a Dictionary (or list if using parameter objects) and then use a loop to add them...

```
var params = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"param1", "value1"},
    {"param2", "value2"},
};

foreach(var param in params)
{
    SqlDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value)
    );
}
```